# shorthand IF/ELSE conditional PHP - what am I doing incorrect?

Tags: php, mysql, select, selected

I am trying to implement a default SELECTED option in my SELECT/OPTION HTML tags based on a mySQL query but when the condition is true "selected" isn't displayed:

```
<select>
<option value=1 <?php ($rowRR[assignedRad]=1 ? ' selected="selected"' : '');?> >GE</option>
<option value=2 <?php ($rowRR[assignedRad]=2 ? ' selected="selected"' : '');?> >AN</option>
<option value=3 <?php ($rowRR[assignedRad]=3 ? 'selected' : '');?> >DD</option>
<option value=4 <?php ($rowRR[assignedRad]=4 ? 'selected' : '');?> >JS</option>
</select>
```

I should not that when I echo $rowRR[assignedRad] it returns the value INT so this isn't the issue.  The mySQL query is good.

either selected="selected" or just 'selected' doesnt work.. I tried both.

Comment: @David Technically you can (depending on the PHP version), but it's strongly discouraged.

Comment: I feel my server would spew anger and errors if I tried that!

Comment: @David That would be epic, but... http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Answer (score 4):

You need a double == not a single. 
A single equals sign is for assignment. double is for comparison

You are also missing an echo statement

Comment: Or he needs to switch to shorttags (`<?=`) , which work the same as `<?php echo ...`

Comment: @TiesonT. That is assuming short tags is enabled (pre 5.4). Since he isn't using the short tag already, I wouldn't want to assume that

Comment: @Kris aren't we all using the latest greatest? P

Comment: It depends on the hosting provider. It is always safer to use <?php echo (...) ?>.

Comment: thanks for all your answers.. shortly after posting this I realized I missed the 'echo' portion.. thanks for the advice regardless.. you guys are awesome

Answer (score 3):

```
<select>
<option value=1 <?php echo ($rowRR['assignedRad']==1 ? ' selected="selected"' : '');?>     >GE</option>
<option value=2 <?php echo ($rowRR['assignedRad']==2 ? ' selected="selected"' : '');?> >AN</option>
<option value=3 <?php echo ($rowRR['assignedRad']==3 ? 'selected' : '');?> >DD</option>
<option value=4 <?php echo ($rowRR['assignedRad']==4 ? 'selected' : '');?> >JS</option>
</select>
```

So you forgot ECHO and you need a double ==.